# run eslint in a separate process in webpack

Tags: eslint, eslint-loader

I'm using `eslint` and `eslint-loader` with `webpack`. My eslint has so many rules that its execution takes up to 50% of the whole build time.

I wonder if there's a way to run eslint in a separate process like similar to `ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin`.

I also tried using `thread-loader`, but instead by time even grew up even more:

```
{
  test: /\.(ts|vue)$/,
  use: ["thread-loader", "eslint-loader"],
  exclude: /node_modules/
}
```